# getelementsbyid of an array node object stdClass Object

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, codeigniter, getelementbyid

I have this array of object:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => a
        [cost] => 5
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => kraftmagar
        [cost] => 10
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 3
        [name] => prepugilistica
        [cost] => 20
    )
)
```

I have put this array in form_dropdown (select) and create a text box to get immediately the select pick

```
echo form_dropdown('rif_corso', $corsi, '', 'onChange="run();"     id="corsi"')

$data = array(
      'type'  => 'text',
      'name'  => 'tot',
      'id'    => 'tot',
);

echo form_input($data);
```

this is the javascript function

```
function run() {
    document.getElementById("tot").value = document.getElementById("corsi").value;
}
```

when the select changes, I want to get the field named "cost" not the id of the record

```
[0] => stdClass Object
(
    [cost] => 5 //  I want this
)
```

Comment: Do you mean `echo $yourVariable[0]->cost;`?!

Comment: @Rizier123 yes i mean this but in javascript

Comment: `arrayName[0].cost` or `arrayName[0]['cost']` ?

Comment: @mtizziani can you write verbose for me ?
document.getElementById ..........

Comment: remove unnecessary sentences

Comment: @VaibhavMule what can i do ? can you explane me

Answer (score 0):

use `document.getAttribute()` as below:If you are getting value of id properly.The following statement get the value of cost.

```
function run() {
var dropdown = document.querySelector('#corsi');
document.getElementById("tot").value = dropdown.getAttribute("cost");
}
```

Comment: what is `$corsi`?in dropdown

Comment: is the array of object ... in $corsi there is attribute cost

Comment: i dont know what is "three dropdowns" but corsi is in a dropdown (like html select)